# If statement not running inside a setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, time, setinterval

Here is the code I'm working with

```
var d = new Date(), // New Date object
    M = d.getMonth(), // Month
    D = d.getDate(), // Day of the month
    h = d.getUTCHours(), // Hours in 24 hour time
    m = d.getUTCMinutes(); // Minutes

    console.log(M+'/'+D+' '+h+':'+m);

    var href = location.href;
    if(M == 1 && D == 13 && h >= 21 && m >= 17){
        // It is time so lets just go there
        window.location = href+'live';
    }else{
        // It isn't already time so lets check every 30 seconds
        setInterval(checkTime, 1000)
    }
    function checkTime() {
        if(M == 1 && D == 13 && h >= 21 && m >= 17){
        // It is time so lets just go there
        window.location = href+'live';
        }
        console.log('checked time');
    }
```

I'm trying to check the date and time and if it's the correct date and time, forward to a different page, if it's not, then check every few seconds (every 1 second for now but I'll probably bump this up to 15 or 30) and check again and if it is now the correct date and time then forward to the new page.

The first if statement works but it doesn't seem to be running the if statement inside of the set interval function.

Maybe I just don't understand how setInterval works totally but I can't see a problem with me code.

Comment: Shouldn't checkTime call  setInterval(checkTime, 1000) again?

Comment: @Dalorzo nope, it shouldn't.

Comment: @jCuber that is really wrong!

Comment: @Dalorzo that you will keep making multiple intervals, it is not Timeout...

Answer (score 2):

Because you are NOT updating the variables, the values never change.

You need to do the date object check every time. They do not update.

The following

```
d = new Date(), // New Date object
M = d.getMonth(), // Month
D = d.getDate(), // Day of the month
h = d.getUTCHours(), // Hours in 24 hour time
m = d.getUTCMinutes(); // Minutes
```

needs to be in your checkTime method.

Comment: Duh, thank you, should have caught that, it's been a long day.